# See if this functional equation works for some function and write down the domain and co-domain

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

$f(x+y)=[f(x)]^2+y$

Prove whether or not this functional equation works for some function and, if it does, specify the domain(s) and co-domain(s).

P.S.: I've invented this problem from scratch just a couple of minutes ago. I hope to see some interesting results and proofs.

EDIT: I was thinking this while trying to solve this equation. Assume the function is constant. This means that i can write $f$ as $f(a)=c$. Therefore i can rewrite the equation as $c=c^2+y$ and so $y=c-c^2$. But that is a contradiction, since I've written a variable ($y$) in terms of a constant ($c$). As a consequence of this, let's try $y=0$: $f(x) = [f(x)]^2$. The only solutions to this are $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=0$, but both are impossible, since we just proved that the function cannot be constant. If my reasoning is correct, this should imply that the function does not allow $y=0$ in its domain.

Comment: What have you tried?  The fact that $f(x+y)=f(y+x)$ might help.  As might $f(0+x)=f(x)=f(x+0)$.

Comment: Putting $y=0$ it becomes $f(x)=[f(x)]^2$ so $f(x)$ is always $0$ or $1$ for any $x.$

Comment: Andry--- I'll upvote the question since I just worked on it and found something (see my answer) that I didn't expect, namely the smallest nonempty domain one could imagine. Let me know if I missed anything in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

The functional equation [for reference] is: $$f(x+y)=f(x)^2+y\ . \tag{1} $$
I'll be assuming both the domain and codomain are subsets of the reals, to be determined by $(1).$
If in this we put $y=0$ and keep $x,$ we get to
$$f(x)=f(x)^2. \tag{2}$$
This immediately implies the range of $f$ is a subset of $\{0,1\}.$

Next going back to $(1)$ we now put $x=0$ and keep $y,$ and get
$$f(y)=f(0)^2+y\ . \tag{3}$$
At this point we know as noted that $f(0)=0$ [''case A''] or else $f(0)=1$ [''case B''].

In case A $(3)$ becomes $f(y)=y.$ But since then $y$ is in the range of $f$ it is $0$ or $1$ and we now know in case A the domain must be a subset of $\{0,1\}.$

In case B $(3)$ becomes $f(y)=1+y.$ Here from $1+y \in \{0,1\}$ we see in case B the domain is a subset of $\{-1,0\}.$

Already things are quite restricted. But we can go one more step by returning to $(1)$ and this time putting $y=x$ keeping both variable to get to
$$ f(2x)=f(x)^2+x. \tag{3}$$
Going back to cases A,B we now see that in case A, $x$ cannot be $1$ else $2$ is in domain of $f.$ And in case B, $x$ cannot be $-1$ else $-2$ ends up in the domain of $f.$ The upshot is that in either case A or B the domain of $f$ is the single number $0.$ Finally the range of $f$ is in either case only $0$ by putting $x=0$ into $(3).$ I think the codomain could be just $0$ or could be $\{0,1\}.$

Comment: After it says "In case A" and "In case B" you've put "(2)". I think there you were actually referencing "(3)".

Comment: @AndryCraft69 You're right. Thanks, will fix.